# html2canvas border image issue

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas library to take screenshot of html view.

but background-image failed to load. i am getting error message Error loading background:

here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/1042/).

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        useCORS:true,
        logging:true,
        allowTaint:true
    });
}
```

```css
#target{
    width:300px;
    height:160px;
    background:lightblue;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/20974/pexels-photo.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

#borderimg1 { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
}

#borderimg2 { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
<div id="target">
    
<p>The border-image property specifies an image to be used as the border around an element:</p>
<p id="borderimg1">Here, the middle sections of the image are repeated to create the border.</p>
<p id="borderimg2">Here, the middle sections of the image are stretched to create the border.</p>

<p>Here is the original image:</p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png">
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 10, and earlier versions, do not support the border-image property.</p>

</div>
```

[image for error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDFai.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Internet security reasons, trying to use an image from a different domain in a canvas causes problems. There are two html2canvas options, useCORS and proxy, which are designed to try to get around that problem.

You have to create the proxy in you project and use that into html2canvas proxy option.

Click [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Proxies) to view sample proxy created in different programming languages.

Usage of proxy in `html2canvas`(`c#` example)

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    "logging": true, //Enable log (use Web Console for get Errors and Warings)
    "proxy":"html2canvasproxy.ashx",
    "onrendered": function(canvas) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        };
        img.error = function() {
            if(window.console.log) {
                 window.console.log("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
            } else {
                alert("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
            }
        };
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but. I think issue not with proxy. issue with **border-Image**. border image option only not working in my cause. Only black border showing instead of image. other than background images are loading well. Please refer code snippet or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/1042/). click on **toImage** button  to see the result. I hope you will understand and help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: See this updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/1047/). My problem only with **border-image**. 
   
` -webkit-border-image: url("http://..*.png") 10 fill stretch;
    border-image-source: url("http://...*.png");
`

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
It's just because of not surpoted problem.

Check this:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features

## Unsupported CSS properties

### These CSS properties are NOT currently supported

- background-blend-mode
- **border-image**
- box-decoration-break
- box-shadow
- filter
- font-variant-ligatures
- mix-blend-mode
- object-fit
- repeating-linear-gradient()
- writing-mode
- zoom

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution to this. Putting a rectangle as border for each PDF page and also starting the second page, and other pages from a litte down, by making difference in the pageHeight.

You can try it like this:

```
html2canvas(myCanvas).then(function(canvas) {

  var imgWidth = 210;
  var pageHeight = 290;
  var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;


  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
  var position = 0;
  var pageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
  var imgData = encodeURIComponent(pageData);
  doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  doc.setLineWidth(5);
  doc.setDrawColor(255, 255, 255);
  doc.rect(0, 0, 210, 295);
  heightLeft -= pageHeight;

  while (heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    doc.setLineWidth(5);
    doc.setDrawColor(255, 255, 255);
    doc.rect(0, 0, 210, 295);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  }
  doc.save('file.pdf');
});
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.